# Is there a way to receive form-data with files using java effectively?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, form-data

I'm trying to find an effective way to receive several files in Java. I tried to use form-data and read several files but looks like Spring doing some manipulation with input data and wasting a lot of time. It's not so bad when I'm trying it locally but when I  tried to upload a file via network things much worse.

Here are 4 endpoints that I used in this test:

```
@SneakyThrows
@PostMapping(value = "upload/formData/v1", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public void uploadFileUsingFormData(@RequestParam Map<String, MultipartFile> files) {
    log.info("Received request, started downloading");
    for (Map.Entry<String, MultipartFile> entry : files.entrySet()) {
        var watch = new StopWatch();
        watch.start();
        var bytes = entry.getValue().getBytes();
        watch.stop();
        log.info("Got file with key: {}, size: {}, time spent: {} ms", entry.getKey(), bytes.length, watch.getTotalTimeMillis());
    }
    log.info("----------------------------------------");
}

@SneakyThrows
@PostMapping(value = "upload/formData/v2", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public void uploadFileUsingFormDatav2(HttpServletRequest request) {
    log.info("Received request, started downloading");
    Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
    for (Part part : parts) {
        var watch = new StopWatch();
        watch.start();
        var bytes = part.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
        watch.stop();
        log.info("Got file with key: {}, size: {}, time spent: {} ms", part.getName(), bytes.length, watch.getTotalTimeMillis());
    }
    log.info("----------------------------------------");
}

@SneakyThrows
@PostMapping(value = "upload/formData/v3", consumes = "multipart/form-data")
public void uploadFileUsingFormDatav3(MultipartHttpServletRequest request) {
    log.info("Received request, started downloading");
    Collection<Part> parts = request.getParts();
    for (Part part : parts) {
        var watch = new StopWatch();
        watch.start();
        var bytes = part.getInputStream().readAllBytes();
        watch.stop();
        log.info("Got file with key: {}, size: {}, time spent: {} ms", part.getName(), bytes.length, watch.getTotalTimeMillis());
    }
    log.info("----------------------------------------");
}


@PostMapping (value = "upload/binary")
public void acceptData(InputStream dataStream) throws Exception {
    log.info("Received request, started downloading");

    var watch = new StopWatch();
    watch.start();
    var bytes = dataStream.readAllBytes();
    watch.stop();
    log.info("Got file, size: {}, time spent: {} ms", bytes.length, watch.getTotalTimeMillis());

    log.info("----------------------------------------");
}
```

Here I'm trying to get files in 4 ways (3 similar, it looks like they are the same) and just a binary. Unfortunately for me, binary upload works almost 2 times faster for the same file.

Here is perf test for binary: [image]

and for form data: [image]

Note: v2 and v3 for multipart work in the same way with similar time. Java 17, gradle: 8.4, Spring 3.2.0. Please advise.

Comment: Start reading here https://spring.io/guides/gs/uploading-files/ for handling file uploads in the "springboot way". Anyway, at this point that seems a micro optimization with req/resp below 1s. When this is slow, probably there is a network "problem" elsewhere.

Comment: I belive it is not a network problem just because in the first case it is just uploading to localhost. Second case I tried to upload in local network (with pretty good speed) and uploading binary much faster than form data

Comment: I assure you, there are millions of springboot apps out there with no concerns about file upload.  A difference of 90ms can be anything on your local machine. You should clarify what is your problem.